# Joining outer table field to subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

Say I have a table `tblNumbers` with four fields, `fldIndex` and `fldNumber` and two joining fields of `fldLink1` and `fldLink2`. I need to add fldNumber of a given index with the fldNumber of the given index + 1. I have tried as follows but am not sure how to properly specify the where clause in the inner table...

```
SELECT T2.fldNum + T1.fldNumHalf AS fldNum
FROM tblNumbers AS T2 INNER JOIN (SELECT fldNum/2 AS fldNumHalf
                            FROM tblNumbers
                            WHERE fldIndex = T2.fldIndex + 1) T1 ON
tblNumbers.fldLink1 = T1.fldLink1 AND tblNumbers.fldLink2 = T1.fldLink2
```

The way I have it now it is not working, can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

```
Sample Data...
fldLink1   fldLink2   fldNum   fldIndex
2400       5          1.53     0
2400       5          2        1
2400       5          3.53     2
2400       5          4.25     3
2400       5          4.86     4
2400       5          5        5
2400       5          6        6
2400       5          7        7

tblNumbers.fldNum would be...
4.25

T1.fldNumHalf would be...
4.86  

The final field value would be...
6.68
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired output?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have provided some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a subquery in this case, just a regular join:

```
SELECT 
    t2.fldnum t2f,t3.fldnum t3f,
    T2.fldNum + T3.fldnum/2 AS fldNum
FROM 
    tblNumbers AS t2
    INNER JOIN tblNumbers AS t3
    ON t2.fldIndex+1=t3.fldIndex
        AND t2.fldLink1=t3.fldLink1
        AND t2.fldLink2=t3.fldLink2
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ea28a/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to add consecutive rows.  I have no idea where the "half" is coming from.  Nor do I understand why you care about the first two columns:

```
SELECT (T2.fldNum + T1.fldNum) / 2 AS fldNum
FROM tblNumbers T1 INNER JOIN 
     tblNumbers T2
     on T2.FieldIndex = t1.FieldIndex + 1
WHERE t1.FieldIndex = 3;
```